# Result from EXISTS section

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
  IF (
    EXISTS (
      SELECT 
        name_short,
        name_full,
        ...
      FROM
        (SELECT 
          ...
        FROM
          ...
        WHERE ...
        GROUP BY ...
        ORDER BY ...) a 
      UNION
      ALL 
      SELECT 
        name_short,
        name_full,
        ...
      FROM
        (SELECT 
          ...
        FROM
          ...
        WHERE ...
        GROUP BY ...
        ORDER BY ...) b
    ) = 0,
    'empty set',
    'not empty set'
  ) ;
```

It is working properly and if the request within `EXISTS` function returns an empty string, the resulting message is `'empty set'`, otherwise - `'not empty set'`. I want to get the values of `name_short` and `name_full` fields if the request within `EXISTS` function returns data (not an empty string). How this can be done without duplicating code?

Comment: What exactly your result is?

Comment: Now the resulting message can be only 'empty set' or 'not empty set', but  I want to get the values of `name_short` and `name_full` fields if the request within EXISTS function returns data (not an empty string).

Comment: So if exist, you want short and full name, these two should be concated? And if not exist, you want 'empty set'?

Comment: Yes, if exist, I want `'name_short'` and `name_full`, not necessary concatenated, and if not exist, then `'empty set'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't, you are much better off just performing your `SELECT` and then handling the results, or lack of results, appropriately. Not only can you not avoid duplicating the query; if it returns more than a single result consisting of a single field, it cannot be used in the `IF(condition, A, B)` function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this, just as a hint:)

```
select
    ifnull(name_short, t.str) as `name_short`,
    ifnull(name_full, t.str) as `name_full`,
    ...
from (select 'empty set' as str) t
left join (
  SELECT 
    name_short,
    name_full,
    ...
  FROM
    (SELECT 
      ...
    FROM
      ...
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY ...
    ORDER BY ...) a 
  UNION
  ALL 
  SELECT 
    name_short,
    name_full,
    ...
  FROM
    (SELECT 
      ...
    FROM
      ...
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY ...
    ORDER BY ...) b) t1 on 1 = 1
```

And here is a demo.

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7708/10)